# Error after joining objects in Apache Pig

Tags: join, apache-pig, dump

I have two data objects in pig.

data_1:

```
col_a: chararray,
col_b: int,
col_c: int,
col_d: chararray
```

data_2:

```
col_a: chararray,
col_b: chararray,
col_c: int,
col_d: int,
col_e: int
```

I want to join the two of them, I tried:

```
all_data = JOIN data_1 BY (col_a) LEFT, data_2 by (col_b);
all_data = JOIN data_1 BY (col_a), data_2 by (col_b);
```

When I tried to dump the object (after limit it to 10 records) Both options gave back the same error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: all_data_limit: Limit - scope-6383 Operator Key: scope-6383): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: all_data: New For Each(true,true)[tuple] - scope-6382 Operator Key: scope-6382): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.impl.io.NullableText cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.impl.io.NullableBytesWritable
```

- "Describe" for both objects (data_1, data_2) gave back good output (what I wrote at the top)
- "describe" for the Joined object - all_data, also gave back a good output, as it should.
- I printed LIMIT 10 for both objects - they have good data.
- I'm using an Amazon cluster "emr-5.2.0", with Pig version 0.16.0

I'm getting a bit frustrated, couldn't find a solution to this and I'm searching for one for 3 days now...
Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: Post your entire script and sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below commands

```
all_data = JOIN data_1 BY TRIM(col_a) LEFT, data_2 by TRIM(col_b);
all_data = JOIN data_1 BY TRIM(col_a), data_2 by TRIM(col_b);
```

let me know if it'd worked without an error.

Comment: It actually worked - even though I didn't need to remove any spaces... Can you explain why it helps? Why is it a problem in the new Pig versions? It also solved the same problem with a script that ran great on pig 0.12 and gave me the same error on pig 0.17. And thank you very much!!